# Is it possible to initialize an array of values for a vector during copy construction using the initializer list?

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor, stdvector

I would like to add values from one to nine into my vector using the copy constructor's initializer list instead of calling pushElements in the body of the constructor. How is this possible?

```
Hane::Hane(int val, bool veri){

}

Hane::Hane():m_myvalue(0), m_myveri(false) {
    pushElements();
}
Cell::~Cell() {}

void Cell::pushElements() {

     m_vector = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

}
```

from Hane.h

```
 private:

std::vector<int> m_vector;
```

Comment: Where is your target vector?

Comment: I have added the code where I declare the vector in the .h file

Comment: Why are you declaring it again in pushElements() function?

Comment: I am new to c++, I am not sure how to push values into it. I made that method but I want to get rid of it alltogether and give the  values to the vector during copy construction instead

Comment: @RamzahRehman I fixed the redecleration

Comment: So what happened when you tried to use the initialization list instead?

Comment: It just gave me  the error 
no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector [with _Ty=int, _Alloc=std::allocator<int>]" matches the argument list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the [constructor that takes an initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (8):

```
struct myclass
{
    std::vector<int> m_vector;
    myclass() : m_vector{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 } {}
};
```

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6acaa666c481cce9)

... or even simpler, initialize the vector directly:

```
struct myclass
{
    std::vector<int> m_vector{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
};
```

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef7466b0ff223a37)